# English Sefarim on Ma'aser Kesafim

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, english, maaser-tithes

Would anyone know of any English *Sefarim* on the *Halachos* of *Ma'aser Kesafim*(money)?

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=maaser+kesafim) has 6 books on the subject of Maaser Kesafim. [Maaser Kesafim and the Development of Tax Law](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2130768) points to the [Florida Tax Review](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2130768##) article on the subject.

Halachos of Ma'aser Kesafim Apr 4, 2011 by Rabbi Yisroel Bronstein is the newest book on the Amazon page.

Maaser Kesafim: Giving a Tenth to Charity says on the cover that it was edited by Cyril Domb. There is an [online version](https://books.google.com/books?id=9xAMt6SW0RMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) that you can read.